# Ctrl+X doesnt cut the line in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

`Ctrl+X` stopped cutting the line in Sublime Text 3, when there's no selection. (both `Windows`/`Linux`)

How to get that behaviour back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your user preferences (**`Preferences -> Settings-User`**), set

```js
"copy_with_empty_selection": true
```

This will allow you to copy and cut the current line to the clipboard, even if it's not selected.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Shift+K`, or you [define](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/customization/key_bindings.html) your own shortcut

Comment: That will delete the whole line, not cut it to the clipboard.

Comment: Ah, I thought that's what he asked for

Comment: I need to CUT the line into clipboard, not just delete